# Simulate low upload internet speed

Tags: performance, networking, testing, simulate

I have a C# Winform desktop app.

I am uploading byte arrays to my server.

I have am using Virgin Media internet and I have an upload speed of 10mb.

I would like to stress test my app for low upload speeds for my app before deployment.

Are there any tools I could use to simulate this? I have seen on this site tools for doing this but testing web sites.  I am testing uploading...

Thanks

Comment: See here for a couple of options: http://superuser.com/questions/135719/how-can-i-limit-bandwidth-of-other-programs

Comment: thanks. I am looking at the free version now